# Convert apache-cordova app to web

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, apache-cordova

I have a Apache-cordova app, for iOS and Android. Now I wanna make a web. I know that we can use reuse HTML5, CSS3, Angular. There is a way to make a migration for web? Because also we use Ionic framework.

Someone a way or we have to start again and reuse some javascript file?

Thanks

Comment: Web should be possible out-of-the-box. You only have to do feature detection for cordova specific api like device, etc.

Comment: Exactly. That's the point

Comment: I think the Ionic may be the hardest part. I'm having a Cordova + Angular + Bootstrap application, which just works on Chrome(Web SQL), which makes testing much easier. So, maybe remove Ionic :).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are asking if it is possible to use cordova plugins in the browser. The short answer is yes, it's possible. The catch is that many cordova plugins aren't supported by the browser.

To add browser support in cordova, you can add it as a platform similar to the way you add iOS & Android: `ionic platform add browser`.

You will need to check the documentation of each of the cordova plugin you want to use to see if they support the browser platform.